# CakePHP: Use value from dropdown to populate a view

Tags: php, cakephp

This is one of those things that I feel should be easier than I'm making it. I have a dropdown list populated with values from a table. I want the user to select a list item and have that list item be the ID for returning a set of rows on a subsequent view. Here is the dropdown code from my view:

```
    echo $this->Form->input('mission_id', array('label' => 'Mission ID'));
    echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'index'));
```

And here is the simple browse controller, which currently returns everything in the table:

```
public function browse() {
    $this->set('requirements', $this->Paginator->paginate('Requirement'));
}
```

I cannot figure out how to make the controller receive the value the user selects so that it can filter the next view. When "View" is clicked, it should return about 500 rows that contain the selected ID. I just don't know what to put after 'action' => 'index' to carry it over to the browse controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `input` in a form that submits to your `index` action and replace the link with a submit button:-

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, ['action' => 'index']);
echo $this->Form->input('mission_id', array('label' => 'Mission ID'));
echo $this->Form->submit(__('View'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Then in your `index` action check for the `mission_id` using `$this->request->data` and do whatever it is you need to do with it from there:-

```
public function index() {
    if (!empty($this->request->data['ModelName']['mission_id'])) {
        // do something with submitted mission_id value
    }
}
```

If you really must use a link to submit the form then you'll want to look at using JavaScript to cause the link to submit the parent form. But it is better to use a button for this.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the controller is picking up a value from the dropdown, but it's the auto-increment column from the table instead of the actual value the user selects. When I echo it out, I get "2" instead of "OA-7," which is what I need to filter my result set. OA-7 is entry #2 in the table. What gives?

Comment: @Chris how are you populating the options for `mission_id`? The form should be passing the selected options `value` to the controller, not the text visible to the user. If the values aren't what you want you may need to change the data used to populate the drop-down.

Comment: That might be where I'm going wrong. The table only has two fields, id and mission_id. mission_id is what the user sees, and that is what I need to carry over to my view. Where do I put the logic that would make the value of the selection the visible text?

Comment: Figured it out. Just needed to modify my controller thusly:

find('list'), array('fields' => array('mission_id', 'mission_id')));

The second 'mission_id' was missing. Much obliged for the above!